# In Angular 7 change detection cycle is being called many times

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 7 application, I am seeing that ngDoCheck in my AppComponent is being invoked at least 18 times for simple 'div' 'click' event. If not for that 'click' event, I dont see any invokes at all(this was to rule out mousemovement, I running mousemovement outside angular zone). In my click Handler if I invoke stopPropagation on the event, all the invokes are reduced to at least 2. I am struggling to understand what is causing this high no. of change detection cycles. Could this be because of event handlers in parent elements?

I agree that even though ngDoCheck is being invoked, still wont trigger DOM update as long as the input bindings (for onpush) and view bindings are not changed. But still bothers me,  why its being invoked so many times.

Comment: mouse movements cause a change detection cycle in default change detection, and change detection cycles propagate up and down your component tree. switch to on push detection if you have performance issues. otherwise don't worry about it.

Comment: execution of `ngDoCheck` does not necessarily equate to running of change detection cycle. see this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5

Comment: I agree that even though ngDoCheck is being invoked, still wont trigger DOM update as long as the input bindings (for onpush)/view bindings are not changed. But still bothers me,  why its being invoked so many times.

Comment: using an empty angular project and binding click in the main component gives me 1 check per click. having mousedown and mouseup as well gives 3 checks. 18 seems like a lot, but without seeing any code it is impossible to tell why that happens. a good way of finding out is to use chromes performance profiler. you can see which check was called by which event, you could also use console.trace() in the ngDoCheck function

Comment: lemme do a console.trace and strip it down to bare minimum code to find out the source of invocation.